# Give an example of a function which is continuous on $\mathbb{Q}\cap[2,4]$ but not uniformly continuous on the same set.

Tags: continuity, epsilon-delta, uniform-continuity

> Give an example of a function which is continuous on $\mathbb{Q}\cap[2,4]$ but not uniformly continuous on the same set.

I'm actually pretty lost with this one. I think I need to create a function that will generate irrationals or something? Any help will be appreciated.

As a side note, this should be solved really using only the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition of uniform continuity.

Comment: If the function is continuous then it must be uniformly continuous because the domain is compact

Comment: @shrinit Why is it compact?

Comment: To ensure that a function is not uniformly continuous, you need some sort of blow up because if the function can be continuously extended to $[2,4]$ it will be uniformly continuous by compactness. Perhaps $f(x) = \frac 1 {x-\pi}$.

Comment: [2,4] is compact and use subspace topology.

Comment: @shrinit but the rationals aren’t closed

Comment: @User8128 I see. So subspace topology does not preserve compactness.

Comment: @shrinit well certainly you can’t claim that every subset of a compact set is compact if that’s what you mean. I think if that were true then every subset of $\mathbb R$ would be compact since you could view the set as a subset of some compactification of $\mathbb R$.

Comment: If you find my proposed edit too nit-picky/pedantic please just say so $\ddot\smile$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go with the function $f(x)=\begin{cases}1&\text{if }x^2>5\\ 0&\text{if }x^2<5\end{cases}$. The function takes finitely many values, and the preimage of points is closed. However, it is apparent that $f$ is not uniformly continuous.

Comment: What do you mean by "the function takes infinitely many values"?

Comment: @VladdyT. "... *finitely* many values".